# SignalR Websocket via K8S ingress

Tags: kubernetes, signalr, nginx-ingress

I have an simple SignalR Client Server setup, where my Server consist of an Webapplication running in a kubernetes cluster, exposing a service via an ingress controller as such:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    # Enable PROXY protocol
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
  name: coreapilocal-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: coreapilocal.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: coreapilocal-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: coreapilocal-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
```

And a HTML Client that  tries to invoke a SignalR Server method via the ingress?
But for some reason is this call being ignored for some reason?

I read somewhere that Http is being stripped by the ingress? and thereby can't recognize the call?
Is there someway to avoid this? or get around this?

I tried above given a different post I found here in SE, but this does not seem to work in my case..

Comment: We might need more details before be able to help you but prior to that: have you seen [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)?

Answer (score 0):

For SignalR to work (and in general for WebSockets) you should enable [Sticky Sessions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/)

Add the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"` to the ingress workload definition:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    # Enable PROXY protocol
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
  name: coreapilocal-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: coreapilocal.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: coreapilocal-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: coreapilocal-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
```

Comment: Seems like the issue was caused by something way different -  being me using an incorrect SignalR library

Comment: Is your issue solved? Do you need more help with this?